# How to add list of nodes to a SpatialLayer

Tags: cypher, neo4j-spatial

I'm new to Neo4j and cypher.
I have many nodes, that i want to add  to a spatial layer.

 This is what i tried with cypher :

**Creating Nodes from a csv file**

```
load csv with headers from "file:///green_tripdata_2015-02.csv" as line
create(pl:pickup_location{lat:line.Pickup_latitude,lon:line.Pickup_longitude});
```

**Spatial Layer Creation**

```
CALL spatial.addPointLayer('nyc');
```

and then :

```
MATCH (pl:pickup_location)
WITH collect(pl) AS pickup
CALL spatial.addNodes('nyc',pickup) YIELD count
RETURN count
```

and i get this error :

```
 Neo.ClientError.Statement.PropertyNotFound: NODE[397] has no property with propertyKeyId=8.
```

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved my problem by just changing:

1) **lat** property to **latitude** 
2) **lon** property to **longitude** 
3) cast with **toFloat()** the two properties(they were Strings in the csv):

toFloat(line.Pickup_latitude) and toFloat(line.Pickup_longitude)