# NODE[37] has no property with propertyKeyId=8

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-spatial

I'm stuck here,
what does this error means  :

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.PropertyNotFound: NODE[37] has no property with propertyKeyId=8.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You need to give us way than that. Can you add the command you are running?

Comment: actually i solved my problem few minutes ago , the issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861988/how-to-add-list-of-nodes-to-a-spatiallayer).